# spaCy NLP custom rule matcher

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I am begginer with NLP. I am using spaCy python library for my NLP project. Here is my requirement,

I have a JSON File with all country names. Now i need to parse and get goldmedal count for the each countries in the document. Given
below the sample sentence,

```
"Czech Republic won 5 gold medals at olympics. Slovakia won 0 medals olympics"
```

I am able to fetch country names but not it medal count. Given below my code. Please help to proceed further.

```
import json
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

with open("C:\Python36\srclcl\countries.json") as f:
    COUNTRIES = json.loads(f.read())

nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))
doc = nlp("Czech Republic won 5 gold medals at olympics. Slovakia won 0 medals olympics")
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
patterns = list(nlp.pipe(COUNTRIES))

matcher.add("COUNTRY", None, *patterns)


for sent in doc.sents:
    subdoc = nlp(sent.text)
    matches = matcher(subdoc)
    print (sent.text)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        print(subdoc[start:end].text)
```

Also, if the given text is like ,

```
"Czech Republic won 5 gold medals at olympics in 1995. Slovakia won 0 medals olympics"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacy provides [Rule-based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) which you could use.

They can be used as follows:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=["ner", "parser"])

countries = ['Czech Republic', 'Slovakia']
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
for a in countries:
    ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "country", "pattern": a}])
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)


doc = nlp("Czech Republic won 5 gold medals at olympics. Slovakia won 0 medals olympics")

with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end])


from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern =[{'ENT_TYPE': 'country'}, {'lower': 'won'},{"IS_DIGIT": True}]
matcher.add('medal', None, pattern)
matches = matcher(doc)


for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span)
```

output:

> Czech Republic won 5
>   Slovakia won 0

The above code should get you started. Naturally, you will have to write your own more complex rules so that you can handle cases like: 
"Czech Republic unsurprisingly won 5 gold medals at olympics in 1995."
And other more complex sentence structures.